# Desktop push notifications not displayed for chrome (macOs)

Tags: angular, macos, google-chrome, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've integrated FCM based push notifications to my angular app, push notifications are getting triggered for ubuntu & windows devices but fails to work on macOs. I am attaching the code of **firebase-messaging-sw.js** :

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    'messagingSenderId': SENDER_ID
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.waitUntil(async function() {
        // Exit early if we don't have access to the client.
        // Eg, if it's cross-origin.
        if (!event.clientId) return;

        // Get the client.
        const client = await clients.get(event.clientId);
        // Exit early if we don't get the client.
        // Eg, if it closed.
        if (!client) return;

        // Send a message to the client.
        self.clients.matchAll().then(function(clients) {
            clients.forEach(function(client) {
                client.postMessage({
                    msg: "Hey I just got a fetch from you!",
                    url: event.request.url
                });
            });
        });

    }());
})

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    // Customize notification here
    const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: 'Background Message body.',
        icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
    };

    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
        notificationOptions);
});
```

Do we have to add any extra configuration to add support for macOs Chrome?

Comment: Hey. DId you find any solutions for mac OS?

Answer (score 11):

For anyone doesn't receive Push notification on your Mac, make sure you have enable Notification for Chrome in System preferences -> Notification -> Chrome

I was struggling with this problem even when I just simply copy and paste codes from Firebase tutorial :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are sending the notification, you may not need to do any of the additional messaging event handling and because you are adding explicit listeners, this may be why it's not working. My `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file simply looks like this

```
// Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
// Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries
// are not available in the service worker.
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.1/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
  messagingSenderId: 'SENDER_ID_HEREE',
});

firebase.messaging();
```

When sending a notification, you simple send a payload like this using the firebase admin sdk on your server. Firebase handles everything else

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
// This is a specific account key file generated through the firebase UI
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "*DATABASE_URL*"
});
const payload = {
  "token": "*DEVICE_TOKEN_HERE",

  "notification": {
    "title": "Test Title!",
    "body": "Test Body."
  },
  "webpush": {
    "fcm_options": {
        "link": "*URL_TO_GO_TO_ON_NOTIFICATION_CLICK*"
    },
    "notification": {
      "icon": "*image to show in the notification ( this path is relative to the site that is displaying the web notification )*"
    }
  }
}
admin.messaging().send(payload).then(res => {
  console.log('SUCCESS ', res)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('uh roh ', err)
})
```